# Unable to instantiate fragment - could not find Fragment constructor

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm trying to call a fragment but receiving the below error sometimes even though I have empty constructor inside my fragment

as

```
public MainFragment()
{

}


Caused by androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$e: Unable to instantiate fragment MainFragment: could not find Fragment constructor
   at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.a(Fragment.java:94)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$6.instantiate(FragmentManagerImpl.java:9)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState.instantiate(FragmentState.java:13)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a(FragmentManagerImpl.java:239)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.a(FragmentController.java:8)
   at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:17)
   at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:10)
   at me.dozee.dozee.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3027)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3182)
   at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
   at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1916)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6898)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: Post full code please of fragment class, more details

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to do anything in your `MainFragment` constructor, just remove it.

If you do need to override the constructor, it should include the call to `super()`

```
public MainFragment() {
    super()
}
```